# Redirect a php script after sending header

Tags: php

I have an html page with a form and a submit button.

Once I click submit all the form data, thanks to fpdf, gets turned into pdf.
This pdf is sent without problems to my email.

Building this little page everything always worked without problems and I was able to redirect my user to a thank you page without problems with this code:

```
header("Location: /thank-you.php",303);
exit();
```

As soon as I've implemented the pdf file save the final redirection stopped working.

I've implemented the pdf save easily with fpdf:

```
$pdf->Output("filename.pdf", "D");
```

And reading on stackoverflow and all the internet I've understood that you can't send two headers.

I thought about solving the problem with javascript so I put after the pdf generation

```
echo "<script language=javascript>
window.location = 'thanks.html'
</script>";
```

but no luck.

The php page simply "stops" when the browser downloads the pdf file.

Any chance to solve this?

EDIT:

All the suggestion I got (thanks to everybody) get me to the same point: use thank you page to handle the pdf save.
Sounds great to me.

I've tried preparing a thankyou.php page with a simple $pdf->Output(); in it.
It didn't work...
So I thought to use an include to my create.php (where happens all the magic: pdf creation, email sending, insert into db etc) with:

```
<?php
include("create.php");
$pdf->Output();
?>
```

Still no luck.

What's wrong with my thinking?

Comment: You can send two headers (or any number, really) just fine. You just can't output content in between headers, or before them.

Comment: When downloading a file, don't output anything else. You'll actually *mix* the outputted content into the downloaded content. If you use Javascript there, your PDF will have those lines in it (and probably corrupt the whole thing).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should approach this the other way around.

Send the user to the thanks page, and on that thanks page do `$pdf->Output()`. That should do what you want.

Comment: The suggestion sounds really great. How can I implement it? I need a thankyou.php I suppose... And then a simple $pdf->Output() should work? Maybe I need to include my create.php, right?

Comment: It doesn't :(
I have in my thankyou.php page just two things: the include and the pdf print.
What happens is that the script starts sending email without ever stopping (the email sending is in my create.php) and never shows my thankyou page (probably because of the create.php include?).
Am I wrong again? Where?

Comment: Follow deceze's advice. That's the way I meant it

Comment: No luck in understanding how to implement it :(

Comment: First, you send the user to the thankyou page. On that thankyou page, you create a javascript redirect to the downloadable file. Because the browser starts downloading it, it keeps the 'old' (thankyou) page and works as it should

Comment: I don't get how to redirect the downloadable file...
I obtain (using fpdf in php) it this way: $pdf->Output(filename.pdf,"D")

Comment: you redirect to the page that creates the pdf. Thus create.php?

Comment: YOWZER IT WORKS! I just need to tweak it a little to keep the form in session so it will keep the data for all the process. God bless you!

Answer (score 3):

Webpages/HTTP is a request-response system. The browser sends *one* request, to which there's exactly *one* response. You simply cannot respond with a PDF *and* a redirect, or a PDF *and* some Javascript.

The typical thing to do is to display the Thank You page first, then inside this page redirect to the file download using Javascript. That way the page stays up and the file downloads.

Comment: Hi there! So that's what I'll do: form.html (simple form post) --> create.php (saves form data in mysql and sends pdf to email) --> thankyou.html (which kind of javascript should I use?) --> save.php ? (maybe in save.php I should just put the function to save the pdf? including create.php?)

Answer (score 1):

You can make thank-you.php send the PDF file. After submitting the form, send the user to the thank-you page then the thank you page will send the user the PDF file. In that way, the thank you page is visible and the page will still be visible after downloading the PDF file.

Comment: Any hints on how? (javascript? which javascript?)